# foreach Dictionary<>.Values or foreach Dictionary<>

Tags: c#, foreach, iteration, containers

I want to know the details of this two styles of iterating `Dictionary` collections in C#:

```
Dictionary<X, Y> xydic = new Dictionary<X, Y>();
```

Style one:

```
foreach (Y y in xydic.Values) { use y }
```

Style two:

```
foreach (var it in xydic) { Y y = it.Value; use y... }
```

I've been C++ developer for years (now I'm working in a C# project) and I don't know the details of how the `Dictionary` collection works, the memory layout or how the elements are iterated so I'm wondering:

`xydic.Values` creates a temporary `List<Y>`? I don't see in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx) any information about the creation of a temporary list.

If a temporary list is created wouldn't this mean that the collection is iterated twice: first to create the `List<Y>` and second to iterate the list itself?

If the the answer to question above is yes, the second style should be more efficient making the first style almost useless so I think that I should be wrong in some way.

I have the feeling that this question should be answered somewhere but I'm unable to locate an answer.

Comment: In C# you don't have to worry about memory. Garbage Collector will do this work for you. If you really want to see how `Dictionary` class execute `.Values` or other functions you could open it with `IlSpy` app and just look at the code

Comment: You could check out the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,467) to see exactly how it is implemented.

Comment: @Jasper my concern is more about if `Values` creates a temporary list (meaning that the collection is iterated twice). When I mentioned that I don't know the memory layout is to remark that if I knew it I could deduce the answer myself :)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster why would not you simply check source - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0 ?

Comment: creates a temporary list (meaning that the collection is iterated twice)   :) :) Typical C++ questions :) :) in C# you have Garbage Collector - don't think about memory allocations a lot - just let the GC do it work

Comment: Rather than worrying about efficiency beforehand, write the code that reads most clearly/cimply to you, then later *measure* performance and only if *this* piece of code needs work, consider changing it. That advice doesn't just apply to C#/.NET.

Comment: @Jasper I don't care about the temporary. I care about iterating the collection twice. I'm ok with letting the GC dispose the temporary but I'm not ok with making the processor do something in two passes when one should be sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Retrieving the `.Values` property of a `Dictionary<,>` is an O(1) operation ([documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx)). The nested type `Dictionary<,>.ValueCollection` is a simple wrapper around the dictionary, so there is no iterating in creating it.

On calling `GetEnumerator()`, you get an instance of the nested, nested `Dictionary<,>.ValueCollection.Enumerator` struct. It acccesses the entries directly through the `private` array `entries` of the `Dictionary<,>`.

You can see the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs).

So your "Style one" above is a good and clear way of doing things, with no performance overhead.

Note that the order in which you get the values, is arbitrary. You do not know how the underlying array `entries` is organized, once the `Dictionary<,>` has had many insertions and removals before you start `foreach`ing it.

However, the order you get with "Style one" and "Style two" is the same; both access the private `entries` array of the `Dictionary<,>` in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

`Values` is not creating a `List<T>`, no.  It's not even pulling the entire set of values into a separate data structure.  All it's doing is creating an enumerator that can iterate over the values.  It's doing exactly the same thing that happens when you iterate the dictionary directly; the difference is that instead of constructing a `KeyValuePair` object for each pair of objects, its only giving you one half of the pair.  Other than that, the iteration process is the same.

Answer (score 2):

All 3 methods (`Keys`, `Values` and just iteration of dictionary) behave the same - iterate internal collection of items in the dictionary. There is no extra lists/arrays created.

The only "extra" work is to check if dictionary was modified after iteration is started (integer comparison).

You can check exact details in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0)

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you are getting [iterator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/65zzykke(v=vs.100).aspx) and not temporary collection. Iterator is using internal state machine to remember what is the current item, and it uses MoveNext method to get nex item.

If you look at IL code you will see more details what is going on inside of foreach. Here is the IL for

```
void Main()
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 1, "one" }, { 2, "two" }};

    foreach (var item in dictionary.Values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

IL Code:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  newobj      System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Int32,System.String>..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.1     
IL_0007:  ldloc.1     
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0009:  ldstr       "one"
IL_000E:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Int32,System.String>.Add
IL_0013:  nop         
IL_0014:  ldloc.1     
IL_0015:  ldc.i4.2    
IL_0016:  ldstr       "two"
IL_001B:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Int32,System.String>.Add
IL_0020:  nop         
IL_0021:  ldloc.1     
IL_0022:  stloc.0     // dictionary
IL_0023:  nop         
IL_0024:  ldloc.0     // dictionary
IL_0025:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Int32,System.String>.get_Values
IL_002A:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Int32,System.String>+ValueCollection.GetEnumerator
IL_002F:  stloc.2     
IL_0030:  br.s        IL_0043
IL_0032:  ldloca.s    02 
IL_0034:  call        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Int32,System.String>+ValueCollection+Enumerator.get_Current
IL_0039:  stloc.3     // item
IL_003A:  nop         
IL_003B:  ldloc.3     // item
IL_003C:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0041:  nop         
IL_0042:  nop         
IL_0043:  ldloca.s    02 
IL_0045:  call        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Int32,System.String>+ValueCollection+Enumerator.MoveNext
IL_004A:  brtrue.s    IL_0032
IL_004C:  leave.s     IL_005D
IL_004E:  ldloca.s    02 
IL_0050:  constrained. System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<,>+ValueCollection.Enumerator
IL_0056:  callvirt    System.IDisposable.Dispose
IL_005B:  nop         
IL_005C:  endfinally  
IL_005D:  ret
```

Comment: Sorry for adding a stupid and naive question for a poor C++ developer who landed on C# world recently... *what is IL*? :D

Comment: IL is Intermediate Language. It is CPU independent, this allows to run .NET code on any platform. .NET code (C#, VB.NET or F#) first compiled to IL code, which is run by CLR (Common Language Runtime) and JITed (Just In Time compiler) to machine code.

Comment: cool, knowing it I would read more about the topic, thanks a lot!